How to use the StringAdapter in pycasbin
pycasbin includes a class StringAdapter in the file adapters/string_adapter.py, however, it doesn't seem to be useable.
Note that it is not an attribute of casbin.persist:
dir(casbin.persist)
['Adapter', 'BatchAdapter', 'FileAdapter', 'FilteredAdapter', 'FilteredFileAdapter', 'UpdateAdapter', '__builtins__', ...]
How can it be used ?
